# how to search for a date by year in sqlite database using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

if we want to search a column or record from table by year and format like year-month-date then how can retrieve. I have a table that have 23 column related to weather i want to access all data 2010 the which query will b used.

i'll try it but it gives no output:

```
c.execute("select * from lahore_weather_2009_May where substr(PKT, 1, 4) = '2011'")
```

and if i applied this code to acess by month then also give no output:

```
validMonth = False
while not validMonth:
    lookForMonth = input('What month, please? (number from 1 through 12):')
    try:
        validMonth = 1<=int(lookForMonth)<=12
    except:
        pass

        sqlCmd = 'SELECT PKT FROM lahore_weather_2009_May WHERE SUBSTR(PKT,4,2)="%.2i"' % int(lookForMonth)
        for row in conn.execute(sqlCmd):
            print (row)
            c.commit()
```

table already created in database

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've tried so far and why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'ii never try it by year i gonna try by month like this

Comment: If the format of the date is YYYY-MM-DD then SUBSTR(PKT,4,2) will not return the month. Use SUBSTR(PKT,6,2).

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have a `DATE` data type, so dates are stored as `TEXT`.
Assuming that your date column has the format `YYYY-MM-DD` you can use the function [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
select * from tablename
where strftime('%Y', datecolumn) = '2010'
```

the pattern `'%Y'` extracts the year of the date.
Or use [`substr()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) to get the starting 4 characters from the date:

```
select * from tablename
where substr(datecolumn, 1, 4) = '2010'
```